# javascript quiz not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I've been trying to have this javascript quiz with 5 questions that can display both an image or an onclick button for sound.

The point of the quiz is to guess which artist belong to which picture or sound. 
But the problems are when I try to add a picture or button in the box where is says "hvilket band er dette?" it crashes the quiz. Also it doesnt seem to count the amount of points for correct and incorrect answears.

Would be greatful if anyone knew how to fix it.
EDIT: also need help with centering the quiz underneath the "banner".
The code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>fagdag 26.04.2016 helårs</title>
  <style>
    #banner {
      text-align: center;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .pulsate {
      -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
      0% {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1.0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
    div#test{ 
    border:#000 1px solid; 
    padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; 
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div onmouseover="PlaySound('mySound')" onmouseout="StopSound('mySound')" id="banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SrnpgpD.jpg" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; text-align; center">
    <img class="pulsate" src="http://i.imgur.com/t2Pil1a.png" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; text-align;center">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<h2> Hvilket band er dette? </h2>
<div id="test"></div>
  <audio id='mySound' src='vivalavida.mp3' />


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function PlaySound(soundobj) {
      console.log("hi")
      var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
      thissound.play();
    }

    function StopSound(soundobj) {
      var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
      thissound.pause();
      thissound.currentTime = 0;
    }
  </script>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, chE, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"B" ],
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"A" ],
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"B" ],
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"D" ],
    [ "Hvilket band er dette?", "Linkin Park", "Green Day", "Coldplay", "Billy Talent", "Hollywoodundead" ,"E" ],

];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>Du fikk "+correct+" av "+questions.length+" spørsmål riktige</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Quiz fullført";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Spørsmål "+(pos+1)+" av "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    chD = questions[pos][4];
    chE = questions[pos][5];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> "+chD+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='E'> "+chE+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Neste</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][5]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error messages on he console?

Comment: Im a bit noobie at this, unsure how to :##

Comment: Click F12 in your browser and check in console running file again

Comment: I get no error message, thats the problem, am I doing something wrong?